# Copying C++ array as a vector of Eigen's matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

I have an Eigen matrix:

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, VECTOR_SIZE> my_matrix(num_vectors, VECTOR_SIZE);
```

And I have a double array with `VECTOR_SIZE` elements:

```
double my_vector_data[VECTOR_SIZE];
```

I want to copy the data from the array `my_vector_data` into some row in `my_matrix`.

How can assign such a C++ vector into a specific row (vector) in the Eigen Matrix?

Answer (score 3):

If you want it more sophisticated than in the answer of @MichaelSmith, this should work for a `std::array` or raw array `data` of size `VECTOR_SIZE`:

```
using FixedSizeRowVector = Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, VECTOR_SIZE>;

size_t some_number = 10;
my_matrix.row(some_number) = Eigen::Map<FixedSizeRowVector> v(data);
```

I can't test it however at the moment.

Comment: What I'm doing currently is very similar to what you're suggesting. The only difference is, that instead of using `.row(rowIndex)`, I am using `.block(rowIndex, 0, 1, VECTOR_SIZE)`

Comment: @SomethingSomething: ok. `row` will likely be an alias of your command so that under the hood the same things are done. Still, I don't think it pays to use a compile-time size  here -- unless you're doing the above very often (-- in which case there will probably be another better solution).

Comment: The `.row(...)` variant is better here since it encodes the size of the block at compile time (you can write `.block<1, VECTOR_SIZE>(rowIndex, 0)` which is almost equivalent to `.row()`) OTOH, your code will likely get optimized to the same machine instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You could copy the data to the matrix by doing the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < VECTOR_SIZE; i++)
{
    my_matrix(0, i) = my_vector_data[i];
}
```

You can find more information about coefficient accessors here: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html#title4.

Comment: Is it only possible to copy them one by one? What about using `Eigen::Map` on the C++ array and assigning it to blocks in the matrix? Is it going to keep looking at my original pointer?

Comment: @SomethingSomething There might be some method that allows you to pass in an array and its size to fill a row, but it would do the same loop under the hood. You could also use `std::copy()` if `Eigen::Matrix`'s have iterators. As for the `Eigen::Map`, I am not sure.